# NoSuchMethodError in Jetpack Compose Navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, build.gradle, android-jetpack, jetpack-compose-navigation

**Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setScreen()Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function3; 
in class Lcom/example/app/presentation/navigation/Screen$ExampleScreen; 
or its super classes (declaration of 'com.example.app.presentation.navigation.Screen$ExampleScreen' 
appears in /data/data/com.example.app.dev/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes2.dex)
at com.example.app.presentation.navigation.NavigationManagerKt$NavigationManager$1.invoke(NavigationManager.kt:242)
at com.example.app.presentation.navigation.NavigationManagerKt$NavigationManager$1.invoke(NavigationManager.kt:34)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:382)
...
```

**Occurrence**

When setting up a screen in the navhost in Jetpack compose

```kotlin
Screen.ExampleScreenObject.let { screen ->
   composable(
      route = screen.getFullRoute(),
      arguments = screen.getArgs(),
      content = screen.screen
  )
}
```

where screen.screen is of type `@Composable (NavBackStackEntry) -> Unit`

Otherwise if I call the screen composable directly it **does not occur**

```kotlin
Screen.ExampleScreenObject.let { screen ->
   composable(
      route = screen.getFullRoute(),
      arguments = screen.getArgs(),
      content = {
          ExampleScreen()
      }
  )
}
```

**Versions**

compose : 1.5.2 
navigation-compose : 2.7.3 
kotlin compose: 1.8.22 
(I'll add more if need be)

**EDIT**

I am also experiencing a similar issue with the NavController

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getBackQueue()Lkotlin/collections/ArrayDeque; 
in class Landroidx/navigation/NavHostController; 
or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.navigation.NavHostController' a
ppears in /data/app/~~HJSBJgaTbw4Lze-D4uCIwQ==/com.example.app.dev-i2HpxAmhqkk6Wwv7O0dNxg==/base.apk!classes32.dex)

at com.example.app.presentation.navigation.NavigatorImpl.logBackStack(NavigatorImpl.kt:21)
at com.example.app.presentation.navigation.NavigatorImpl.access$logBackStack(NavigatorImpl.kt:8)
at com.example.app.presentation.navigation.NavigatorImpl$1.onDestinationChanged(NavigatorImpl.kt:14)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.dispatchOnDestinationChanged(NavController.kt:1002)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1859)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.kt:1283)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.kt:1195)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.kt:100)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:225)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:83)
...
```

Comment: can you share more code of navigation with ```NavHost```.

Comment: @ChiragThummar I was able to fix it thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprits were these two dependencies

```
implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3")
implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3")
```

Specifically the versions

Up them to match navigation-compose versions 2.7.3